# Issues in LINQ to SQL with String Contains Escape seqence of Backspace - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, escaping

I have a table in SQL Serve which contains the following model and values:

```
public class Employee 
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It contains the following values

```
EmpId        Name
______________________________
1            A
2            B
3            C
```

C# code to get the records using `.Contains("A\b")` in LINQ - The search string contains an escape character `\b` Backspace.

```
public class EmployeeService {
    public List<Employee> GetEmployee() {
        return dbContext.Employee.Where(m => m.Name.Contains("A\b")).ToList();
    }
}
```

The `IQueryable` object has the SQL statement

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EmpId] AS [EmpId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 
    [Extent1].[Name] LIKE '%A%'
```

I am unable to get the matching records. Kindly assist me.

The expected matching result of the above SQL Statement is

```
EmpId        Name
______________________________
1            A
```

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: What should be correct/actual result according to query and given data?

Comment: What is the `\b` for in `Contains("A\b");`?

Comment: @wkl - Its a escape character `\b - Backspace`. But it converts the SQL Statement as mentioned in the Question, but its not returning the matching record `EmpId == 1`.

Comment: @Mastero Sorry, I was unclear. I know what it is, but not what you use it for here. Why not just `Contains("A");`? Does it make a difference?

Comment: @wkl I'm writing, a Test cases for a Library method, in that I'm getting the search string with trailing escape sequence `\b`, the resultant of the string  `A\b` is `A`. But I don't know why its failing to retrieve the result.

Comment: Have you tried without the `\b`? Did it work?

Comment: @wkl Yes, its working - for both the cases it generates the same SQL Statement.

Comment: How have you verified that the generated SQL statements are the same? When I run your query, character `\b` is contained in the generated SQL (char 8, which is naturally invisible when printed out), which explains why the query is not returning anything, but the queries look the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\b` character isn't always *visible*, but it's there. You may not see it in your SQL editor, but in other displays the search predicate will look like this:

```
LIKE '%A□%'
```

To fix this, remove non-printable characters from the search string before sending it to the database:

```
var searchString = new string("A\b".Where(c => c > 31).ToArray());
return dbContext.Employee.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why do you not find a match?**

Because there is none. None of your entries contain `"A\b"`. While there is one containing `"A"`, this is not what you asking for in `.Contains("A\b")`.

**Then, why do you get the same sql statement for `.Contains("A")` and `.Contains("A\b")`?**

I think you don't. I think they are only displayed the same way because `\b` cannot be printed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this :

```
public class EmployeeService {
public List<Employee> GetEmployee() {
    return dbContext.Employee.Where(m => m.Name.Contains("A")).ToList();
   }
}
```

Comment: Its not a letter, its a escape sequence `\b - Backspace`

Comment: What do you expect of your query to return ?

Comment: I'm getting the search string with trailing escape sequence `\b`, the resultant of the string `A\b` is `A`. But I don't know why its failing to retrieve the result.

Comment: Why you want to use \b ? what's the problem with : m.Name.Contains("A") ?

Comment: I'm having issues with escape sequence, for both the cases the resultant LINQ to SQL is same (i.e., it generates the same SQL Statement). But If I use the escape char then it fails. I want to know why its failing even-though the SQL statements are identical.

Comment: Ok so I don't know your answer, Someone will help soon I hope ;)